# Find command in matlab, entering a number within a quotation marks

Tags: string, matlab, numbers, find

I am trying to pass a number in the `find` within `' '` quotation marks:

```
v=find(a,'fldr','x ==156');
```

this will work if I manually enter a number next to `x` but instead of `156` I want to iterate this process. I save `156` as `ffid` and try to pass it:

```
ffid = 156
v=find(a,'fldr','x ==ffid')
```

But if I do this, my code fails since the quotation marks makes it literal. Is there a way I can read the number without inserting it as a number manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can try concatenating `ffid` to the `x==` string:

```
ffid = 156;
v=find(a,'fldr',strcat('x==', num2str(ffid)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ffid = 156;
v=find(a,'fldr',sprintf('x==%d',ffid));
```

You can build your string using [`sprintf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html). For non-integer numbers you'll want to change the format specifier (`%f` here).